# How to play audio using the device's volume?

Tags: java, gluon-mobile

The [Audio](https://docs.gluonhq.com/attach/javadoc/latest/com.gluonhq.attach.audio/com/gluonhq/attach/audio/Audio.html) interface allows to set its volume, but apps usually use the Media or Notifications volumes on Android. In a Gluon Mobile app, pressing the volume keys does nothing, while in other apps the device's volume changes.

Tested on Android 8 and 12 using Attach version 4.0.15.

Is there a way to play audio using the device's volume settings and allow the user to adjust the volume from within the device?

Comment: The VideoService does [manage](https://github.com/gluonhq/attach/blob/master/modules/video/src/main/native/android/dalvik/DalvikVideoService.java#L725) the volume changes via the volume keys. It can be used as well to play audio. Can you try it?

Comment: @JoséPereda I tried it, it has a couple of problems: (1) the volume can only be changed while the audio plays, which is hard to do for a short audio clip; the volume buttons do nothing while the app is not playing audio, unlike in other apps. (2) I have 2 short audio clips added to the playlist, setting the current index plays it from the start, even if the index is `1` (2nd file). I think I can solve this by adding/removing from the playlist instead, but still looks like a bug.

Comment: @JoséPereda I managed to use the Video service by repopulating the playlist each time with the specific audio file I want played. Is this the intended way to play a single audio file? Usually playlists have an option to go enable/disable going to the next item after the previous finished.

Comment: Have you tried [`setLooping()`](https://github.com/gluonhq/attach/blob/master/modules/video/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/attach/video/VideoService.java#L171)?

Comment: @JoséPereda The default is `false`, but I set it to `false` explicitly. It doesn't stop the playlist from continuing to the next item. It probably stops looping of the whole playlist.

Comment: @JoséPereda I posted my best attempt at a solution. Is filing a request to improve the capabilities of the Audio/Video services in Attach relevant?

Comment: Of course, contributions are always welcome.

Comment: @JoséPereda I don't think I can create a PR for these. I can only file an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no proper way to do this. Using the `VideoService` it's possible to change the volume of the device, but only while audio is playing, which requires the user to be ready to do so for short audio clips.

The `VideoService` also does not support playing a single file out of a playlist. The only solution I found was switching the playlist to a single audio clip whenever it's required to be played and isn't played already:

```
class MobileNotifier {

    private static final String SMALL_BEEP_PATH = "/sounds/SmallBeep.wav";
    private static final String BIG_BEEP_PATH = "/sounds/BigBeep.wav";

    VideoService service;
    
    private MobileNotifier(VideoService service) {
        this.service = service;
        service.getPlaylist().add(SHORT_BEEP_PATH);
    }
    
    public void play(Alert alert) {
        switch (alert) {
            case SMALL -> {
                if (service.statusProperty().get() != Status.PLAYING || !SMALL_BEEP_PATH.equals(service.getPlaylist().get(0))) {
                    service.stop();
                    service.getPlaylist().set(0, SMALL_BEEP_PATH);
                    service.play();
                }
            }
            case BIG -> {
                if (service.statusProperty().get() != Status.PLAYING || !BIG_BEEP_PATH.equals(service.getPlaylist().get(0))) {
                    service.stop();
                    service.getPlaylist().set(0, LONG_BEEP_PATH);
                    service.play();
                }
            }
        };
    }

}
```